# How to fire a tag if certain element on the page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to fire a tag if "id = success" element on the page. Is that possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you use the new interface (since the old interface will be phased out soon in any case). I will also assume that the "success" element is there when the page is loaded (i.e. not created dynamically).

Go to variables, scroll down to "User Defined Variables2 click "new", select "DOM Element". "Selection method" is preselected as "ID", you can leave that. In "Element ID" enter the, well, ID of your element (i.e. "success" in your case). This variable will hold the text of your "success" element.

Go to triggers. Click "new", then select "Pageview". In the "Trigger Type" dropdown select "DOM Ready" (you can read the ID only after the elements have rendered). The pageview provides the event that is necessary to fire a tag.

Klick "Fire Tag on". In the Dropdown select your custom variable from the previous paragraph. As condition enter "contains" and then one of the words that your success element contains.

Alternatively you should be able, when creating the DOM element, to enter "id" in the "attribute" field. If you fill in the attribute field the variable will hold the value of that attribute, so if you select "id" the variable value will, in your case, be "success".